# Python - make string equal length

Tags: python, string

I have a RNA sequence of varying length. Max length of the sequence is 22. Some sequences are shorter. So if a sequence is shorter then add "0" to the end of the line till the length becomes 22.

How to do it in python?
this is my input

AAGAUGUGGAAAAAUUGGAAUC

CAGUGGUUUUAUGGUAG

CUCUAGAGGGUUUCUG

UUCAUUCGGC

and my expected ouput should be for example in the last line it does not contain 22 characters so  i need to make it 22 by adding zero to it

UUCAUUCGGC000000000000

but as per your commands i am getting out put as 
AAGAUGUGGAAAAAUU
00000
the addtional characters used for justification came down and not in the same line

Comment: I see you're reading the lines from a file, use `rstrip()` to strip the newline characters(`'\n'`) first: `s.rstrip().ljust(22, '0')`

Comment: Worked ..Thanks a lot buddy... WIll be troubling u a lot

Answer (score 17):

Use [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) method:

```
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> s.ljust(22, '0')
'foobar0000000000000000'
```

Comment: @Aswini Chaudhary : but one more problem is when i tried to use them in the code and print the extra zero are printed in next line and not appended to the line for line in file:
 if not line.startswith (">"):
  if len(line) > 22: # maximum length of the miR sequence 
   pass
  else:
   for line1 in line:
    print line.ljust(22,'0');    and the output came like  AAGAUGUGGAAAAAUU
00000
AAGAUGUGGAAAAAUU
00000

Comment: @ramko You shouldn't iterate over the string, simply do: `line1.ljust(22,'0')`

Comment: @ramko Please post your sample data and expected output in the question body, comments are not readable.

Comment: @ Aswini Chadhary : Posted as requested

Comment: @ramko http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216512/python-make-string-equal-length/23216558?noredirect=1#comment35517749_23216512 ;-)

Comment: Being a biology and a little known programming i could not make most of the things , reading books i hell for me so i made a choice to ask you experts thanks a lot for today. willcome with new doubts soon

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to @Aशwini चhaudhary's answer is:

```
s = '{0:0<22}'.format(s)
```

#### Example

```
s = 'hello'
s = '{0:0<22}'.format(s)

>>> print s
hello00000000000000000
```

#### Alternative

Or as शwini चhaudhary suggested, simply:

```
s = format(s, '0<22')
```

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, Thank you, I have included it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it using while loop. Lets say you have all the sequences in a list.

```
x=['AAGAUGUGGAAAAAUUGGAAUC','CAGUGGUUUUAUGGUAG','CUCUAGAGGGUUUCUG','UUCAUUCGGC']
```

now you can run a while loop on the length of the mrna sequence. This loop will check the length of mrna and will continue adding '0' at the end until the length of sequence is 22

```
new=''
for mrna in x:
    new=mrna
    while len(new)<22:
        new=new+'0'
    print(new)

while len(mrna)<22:
   mrna+'0'
```

output will be:

```
AAGAUGUGGAAAAAUUGGAAUC
CAGUGGUUUUAUGGUAG00000
CUCUAGAGGGUUUCUG000000
UUCAUUCGGC000000000000
```